# OpenLayers getfeatureinfo shows all features, even with CQL filter

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, cql-filter

I have a map with several CQL filters that a user can use in my website. When the user applies the CQL filter, I want them to be able to use getfeatureinfo which only shows features from the CQL filter. However, after applying a CQL-filter, it still gives featureinfo of all features, even the ones which are not visible. I looked for solutions here: [OpenLayers CQL filter gets info about NOT VISIBLE features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71261/openlayers-cql-filter-gets-info-about-not-visible-features) and here: [How to add CQL filter into GetFeatureInfo request in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179859/how-to-add-cql-filter-into-getfeatureinfo-request-in-openlayers), but I couldn't solve it myself.

My code looks something like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var control_zoom_max = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent({title:'Zoom naar het volledige kaartbeeld'});
    var control_zoom_in  = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomIn({title:'Zoom gecentreerd in op het kaartbeeld'});
    var control_zoom_out = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomOut({title:'Zoom gecentreerd uit op het kaartbeeld'});
    var control_zoom_box = new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({title:'Zoom in met een te slepen rechthoek'});
    var control_nav_hist = new OpenLayers.Control.NavigationHistory();
    var control_drag_pan = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({title:'Verplaats het kaartbeeld met de linkermuisknop'});
    var control_identify = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        title : 'Klik op een punt of lijn voor informatie',
        layers : [ AmiceHerkomst, AmiceVerwerking],
        maxFeatures: 1000,
        queryVisible : true,
        infoFormat : 'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
        vendorParams: {
            buffer: 5  // geoserver buffer in pixels
        },
        eventListeners : {
            getfeatureinfo : function(event){
                showInfo(event);
            }
        }
    });
});

function updateFilter() {
    var plaatshtml = document.getElementById('filter').value.toLowerCase();
    var volumehtml = document.getElementById('volume').value;
    var volumeType = document.getElementById('filterType').value;
    var jaar = document.getElementById('Jaar').value;
    var maand = document.getElementById('Maand').value;
    var bedrijfhtml = document.getElementById('filternaam').value.toLowerCase();

    var plaatsnaam = "strToLowerCase(plaats) LIKE '%"+ plaatshtml +"%'";
    var volume = "totgw_1 "+ volumeType + " " + volumehtml;
    var datum = jaar + maand;
    var bedrijfsnaam = "strToLowerCase(straatnm) LIKE '%"+ bedrijfhtml +"%'";

    var filterParams = {                    
                    cql_filter: null                   
                };

    if (OpenLayers.String.trim(plaatshtml) != "") {                     
                    filterParams["cql_filter"] = plaatsnaam;                    
                }
    if (OpenLayers.String.trim(volumehtml) != ""){
                    filterParams["cql_filter"] += "AND " + volume;
                }   
    if (OpenLayers.String.trim(bedrijfhtml) != ""){
                    if (filterParams ["cql_filter"] != null){
                        filterParams["cql_filter"] += "AND " + bedrijfsnaam;
                    }
                    else {
                        filterParams["cql_filter"] = bedrijfsnaam;
                    }
                }
    if (OpenLayers.String.trim(jaar) != ""){
                    filterParams["cql_filter"] += "AND " + datum;
                }

    mergeNewParams(filterParams);
}
```

How do I add my CQL-filter parameters into my getfeatureinfo request?

EDIT
this is what the getfeatureinfo request does looking via firebug:
[image]

Comment: Could you write the GefFeatureInfo request that your code generates into your question? What is your GeoServer version?

Comment: How can I see my GetFeatureInfo request? I use GeoServer version 2.5.4

Comment: Make your code to print it for you or use something like Firebug for monitoring what your application is doing. I am not sure when GeoServer was improved so that GetFeatureInfo is very well aware of what is really rendered on the map. Your version is rather old, this improvement may have published after 2.4 version. I would update GeoServer first to 2.9.1 and then to 2.9.2 immediately when it is out.

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture in the Original post with, I think, the getfeatureinfo response when clicking on a point on the map. I don't know if that is what you mean? I hope it is possible to do it with this old version, since our company will not update anytime soon I'm afraid

Comment: What I was after is the real http request like `http://company.com/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeatureInfo&...`. But anyway, I suppose that you have done it right because your map works as you wish but you can't make GetFeatureInfo to care about CQL_FILTER with GeoServer 2.4.6. I posted this also as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I had one note, doesn't this problem have to do with openlayers? I use the WMSGetFeatureInfo function from openlayers. CQL filtering is a function of geoserver (which works as far as building and showing the query result). If you look here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71261/openlayers-cql-filter-gets-info-about-not-visible-features the guy solved the same issue in 2013, which was before 2.5.4 geoserver was released.

Comment: Well, looks like I am wrong with CQL_FILTER. User ianT does know GeoServer. Capture what your app is sending to GeoServer an check if CQL_FILTER is included. When you have the request you can test it with browser or anything and avoid possible issues with your application. Once you know that the server gives the correct answers you can continue and make you application to create correct requests. I will delete my answer soon.